# Conseguir datos en formato JSON

Tags: python-3.7, jupyter, jsonobject

Con el siguiente script, intento conseguir datos en el formato JSON.

```
# source = https://freshprinceofstandarderror.com/finance/fear-and-greed-index-data-in-python/
# getting data in JSON format 

import requests, json
import pandas as pd

BASE_URL = "https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata"
START_DATE = '2021-01-01'

r = requests.get("{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, START_DATE))
data = r.json()
```

Me devuelve el error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_4281/2898561448.py in <module>
      9 
     10 r = requests.get("{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, START_DATE))
---> 11 data = r.json()

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    899             if encoding is not None:
    900                 try:
--> 901                     return complexjson.loads(
    902                         self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs
    903                     )

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    344             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347     if cls is None:
    348         cls = JSONDecoder

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

¿Cómo puedo fijar este error?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Si lo que planteas a como gestionarlo, intenta con un try except, y tratar el JSONDecodeError, para solucionar el error primero imprime que es lo que quiere convertir a JSON y mira que requisitos necesita para convertirlo según la librería,  tiene pinta de que el error está en el tipo de dato que tienes.

Comment: He encontrado esta misma pregunta aqui: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396538/python-requests-jsondecodeerror'. Voy a estudiarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Cuando trabajes con `requests` siempre es importante revisar el estatus de la respuesta para saber lo que está fallando

```
r.status_code
```

Al hacerlo con tu código se puede ver que el estatus que regresa es `418`. Si revisas la [documentación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) puedes ver lo que significa cada número, lo esperado para una petición exitosa es `200`

A tu código le hace falta agregar los `headers`

Si abres directamente en tu navegador el URL que quieres acceder y abres el inspector y vas a la pestaña "Network" vas a poder revisar los `header` que se hacen en la petición, vas a encontrar algo así

```
:authority: production.dataviz.cnn.io
:method: GET
:path: /index/fearandgreed/graphdata/2021-01-01
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en,ja;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,es-MX;q=0.6,es;q=0.5
cache-control: max-age=0
if-none-match: W/7929229685365849036
referer: http://localhost:8888/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36
```

De todos esos, el mínimo necesario para una transacción exitosa es `user-agent`

Al implementar los `header` en tu código ya funciona de forma correcta

```
import requests, json
import pandas as pd

headers = {
   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'
}

BASE_URL = "https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata"
START_DATE = '2021-01-01'

r = requests.get("{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, START_DATE), headers=headers)
data = r.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Versión actualizada del código con manejo de errores.
En mi caso actual, el código devolvió un JSONDecodeError que se debe a que la respuesta de la URL que intenta obtener no tiene un formato JSON válido. Este error suele ocurrir cuando el servidor devuelve una respuesta vacía o una respuesta inesperada que no se puede analizar como JSON.

Para manejar este error, se puede usar un bloque try-except para capturar la excepción y manejarla correctamente.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'
}

BASE_URL = "https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata"
START_DATE = '2021-01-01'

try:
    r = requests.get("{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, START_DATE), headers=headers)
    r.raise_for_status()  # Check for any request errors
    data = r.json()
    # Process the data
    # (You can add your data processing logic here, e.g., storing it in a DataFrame)

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred during the request: {e}")

except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print(f"HTTP Error occurred: {e}")

except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print(f"JSON Decode Error occurred: {e}")
    print(f"Response content: {r.content}")  # Print the response content for debugging

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
data
```