# Importar JSON. error: name 'headers' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, json, jupyter

Este script, debería descargar y mostrar una gráfica de indices, de Internet. Estoy bastante verde en temas python-JSON

```
# !pip install yfinance
# !pip install backtrader[plotting]
import requests, csv, yfinance, pytz, json
from datetime import datetime

BASE_URL = "https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata"
START_DAY = "2021-01-25"
r = requests.get("{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, START_DAY), headers=headers)
data = r.json()
print (json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Me devuelve el error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7309/3957183014.py in <module>
      6 BASE_URL = "https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata"
      7 START_DAY = "2021-01-25"
----> 8 r = requests.get("{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, START_DAY), headers=headers)
      9 data = r.json()
     10 print (json.dumps(data, indent=2))

NameError: name 'headers' is not defined
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: He tomado como referencia esta consulta "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537773/conseguir-datos-en-formato-json" y, añadido "... headers=headers)"" en la línea 8. Headers ¿Que son?. Cabeceras de las columnas del DataFrame final?.

Comment: `headers` son las cabeceras de la petición http. Usualmente se utilizan para especificarle parámetros a tu api como autenticación y ese tipo de cosas. Justo HeytalePazguato te pone en su respuesta el valor de headers que necesitas. Decláralo en tu código https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/537776/186586. Acabo de [probarlo](https://ibb.co/WDnrZxW) y funciona incluyendo la variable headers.

Comment: No tienes ninguna variable `headers` por ninguna parte. La pregunta que citas muestra que `headers` es un diccionario, con precisos valores. Eso falta en tu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que pasas la variable `headers` en la llamada, pero no tienes esa variable definida por ninguna parte.

La solución es inicializar apropiadamente `headers` con un diccionario, tal como lo espera `requests`.

#### Demo

```
import requests, json

cabecera = {
   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'
}
BASE_URL = "https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata"
START_DAY = "2021-01-25"
r = requests.get("{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, START_DAY), headers=cabecera)
data = r.json()
print (json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

produce:

```
{
  "fear_and_greed": {
    "score": 27.3943775100429,
    "rating": "fear",
    "timestamp": "2022-06-04T00:00:10.609000+00:00",
    "previous_close": 27.3943775100429,
    "previous_1_week": 21.9222150554571,
    "previous_1_month": 22.1714285714286,
    "previous_1_year": 42.7666666666667
  },
  "fear_and_greed_historical": {
    "timestamp": 1654300810609.0,
    "score": 27.3943775100429,
    "rating": "fear",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": 1611532800000.0,
        "y": 67.6666666666667,
        "rating": "greed"
      },
      {
        "x": 1611619200000.0,

... etc ... muchas líneas.
```